# What is lighting my scene?

Tags: light

Ok I stumped myself (maybe I need more coffee).

What the heck is lighting my scene!?!?

I have no lights and I turned the HDRI to 0. I also unplugged it.

This is layer one in rendered view with an earth that is completely black (because there are no lights, perfect!).

[image]

This is the layer below in rendered view showing the material, and its lite just fine. This is bad, not what I want.

[image]

Here is the outliner, no lights.

[image]

What am I forgetting?

Comment: Did you check your Ambient Occlusion? ( Property tab > World > Ambient Occlusion )

Comment: Ahh thank you. I knew I was missing something. It is now how I want it.

Comment: @S.Visser Nice find, you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other "light" source in blender is the [Ambient Occlusion](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/world/ambient_occlusion.html). Its not real light but purely a rendering trick that tends to look nice because generally in real-world surfaces that are close together (like small cracks) will be darker than surfaces that do not have anything in front of them, because of shadows, dirt, etc.

You can disable it in the World Properties under the tab Ambient Occlusion.

[image]