# Can’t find light in scene/why is it so bright?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting, world

Ok I have a scene that used to be a darker/less yellow world lighting before I started adding some lights/emissive planes.

I wanted to go back to the lighting I had before, so I changed the world lighting back and deleted the new planes. BUT the lighting is still like this:

[image]

I’ve looked for hidden light planes, hidden suns, and checked world lighting but it’s still yellow tinted.

What could be the reason? How can I get back to the lighting from a previous scene? I’m in cycles

Comment: read this answer and report back: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110446/1853

Comment: Ah.. Note to everyone - apparently suns anywhere light the ENTIRE scene, no matter how far away

Comment: Sun lamps do not behave like normal lamps, their physical placement in the scene is irrelevant, in the sense that they emit light in one direction regardless of their coordinates in 3d space, and they have no fallof.